# How to statically link a Go binary that uses crypto/tls?

Tags: go, static-linking

If you try to compile the following Go program:

```
package main

import _ "crypto/tls"

func main() {

}
```

You'll wind up with a dynamically linked Go binary. This is annoying for me (I'm building a Go binary inside a Docker container, which uses a different libc from my host, which will result in the binary not running on my host).

How does one **force** Go to build such a program statically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only OS where `crypto/tls` uses cgo is darwin, where it needs to call `FetchPEMRoots`to get the root CAs.

The reason your program is using cgo is because `crypto/tls` imports the `net` package, which links to the host resolver by default. You can build the `net` package without cgo using the "netgo" build tag.

```
go build -tags netgo
```

Or if you're on a release where the std lib packages won't be built by default, you can trigger them to be compiled with a new installsuffix

```
go build -installsuffix netgo -tags netgo
```

Since you're not going to have the need or ability to use cgo in your environment, you may want to just build everything with `CGO_ENABLED=0` to disable cgo entirely.